# push html into already created json array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to get my html 'commentlinktoggle' to come through with the rest of my posts array. Yesterday I started learning Json and for the most part i'm not doing too bad. but I'm trying to get my head around array_push, as I assume that is what i need to pass this variable that is not within my database $row loop.So here is what I have and what I need to do.

This is the json response I'm wanting to get out of posts

```
{
    "posts": {
    "sharedcontent_userstimestamp": "<div id='time' title='Posted on Thursday  01 Jan 1970 at 01:00AM '>&#8986;2017 years <\/div>",
    "streamitem_timestamp": "<div id='time' title='Posted on Thursday  23 Feb 2017 at 07:55PM '>&#8986;5 days <\/div>",
    "1": {
    "streamitem_id": "1178",
    "streamitem_content": "Uploaded a new picture<hr>To Album: <a href=photolist.php?uid=3&aid=16>tee<\/a><br\/><br\/>tee",
    "streamitem_type_id": "4",
    "streamitem_timestamp": "2016-12-11 02:58:52",
    "streamitem_collect": "<li><a id=\"collectpostlink1178\" 
    "commentlinktoggle": "<div id='streamcomment' style='cursor:pointer;display:block;' class='toggleon1178'><a style='cursor:pointer;' id='commenttoggle_1178' onclick=\"toggle_comments('comment_holder_1178');swapcommentlabel(this.id);\"><div id='loadcommentcount1178'>Comments 1<\/div><\/a><\/div>"
},
```

But instead its coming out like this. with commentlinktoggle clearly outside the posts array.

```
{
    "posts": {
    "sharedcontent_userstimestamp": "<div id='time' title='Posted on Thursday  01 Jan 1970 at 01:00AM '>&#8986;2017 years <\/div>",
    "streamitem_timestamp": "<div id='time' title='Posted on Thursday  23 Feb 2017 at 07:55PM '>&#8986;5 days <\/div>",
    "1": {
    "streamitem_id": "1178",
    "streamitem_content": "Uploaded a new picture<hr>To Album: <a href=photolist.php?uid=3&aid=16>tee<\/a><br\/><br\/>tee",
    "streamitem_type_id": "4",
    "streamitem_timestamp": "2016-12-11 02:58:52",
    "streamitem_collect": "<li><a id=\"collectpostlink1178\" style=\"cursor:pointer;color:#000;\" onclick=\"collectpost(2309);\">Collect<\/a><\/li>",       
    }
    },
    "count": 9,
    "commentlinktoggle": "<div id='streamcomment' style='cursor:pointer;display:block;' class='toggleon2309'><a style='cursor:pointer;' id='commenttoggle_2309' onclick=\"toggle_comments('comment_holder_2309');swapcommentlabel(this.id);\"><div id='loadcommentcount2309'>Comments 3<\/div><\/a><\/div>"
}
```

Here is my php code where I've attempted to use array_push to push. I know I've made a mess of it. But if someone could explain where I have gone wrong It would be a fantastic help to me for future reference.

```
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $json = array(
                'posts' => array(),
                'count' => $rowcount,
                'commentlinktoggle'  => $sendcommentlinktoggle,
            );
    $sendcommentlinktoggle = "Some html in here";

    array_push($posts, array('commentlinktoggle'  => ));

    $posts[] = array(
                //Post information and ids
                'streamitem_id' => $row['streamitem_id'],
                'streamitem_content' => $row['streamitem_content'],
                /and so on...
            );
    $rowcount++; 
}
$json['posts'] = $posts;
echo json_encode($json);
```

Also maybe this will help too, my function loop where i append my data

```
    success: function (data) { 
        $.each(data.posts, function(i, response) {
            $("#homestatusid").append(""+response['commentlinktoggle']+"");
        )};
    }
```

If anyone needs anymore information, please ask away and I'll assist the best I can.

Comment: A bit of code indentation would help us all debug your code, **including you**

Comment: I cant give a full answer at the moment but it seems odd that you're sending formatted HTML as JSON. Generally just the data itself would be stored and sent for the JSON response, then the elements would be created and added on the client side.

Comment: Because I use php queries to decide what html to pass over. rather than doing it within the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing to `$posts` and not to the element that you add later, `$post[]` so that is why the element is added outside of the individual posts, on the same level but with an associative key.

The easiest solution would be to add the element where you add the rest of the content:

```
 $posts[] = array(
    //Post information and ids
    'streamitem_id' => $row['streamitem_id'],
    'streamitem_content' => $row['streamitem_content'],
    //and so on...
    // Add the additional content
    'commentlinktoggle' => $sendcommentlinktoggle,
 );
```

Comment: As easy as that @jeroen. It works perfect. thanks so much.